# Using MFC90 Class exported from DLL with DLL built with MFC100

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc

Please forgive me if this question has been asked before, but I promise I looked extensively and could not find anything (maybe I just couldn't come up with the right search terms).

Here's the situation, I have a DLL built on MFC90 that exports a class (and uses MFC objects in the header file like `CString`, `POSITION`, etc.), we'll call this DLL **ONE**. Since I only have access to VS2010, I'm limited to building MFC based DLLs and Apps on MFC100, and I have another DLL, we'll call it **TWO**, that uses the objects exported from DLL **ONE**. So far it seems to work okay, but I want to know if I should really expect some bugs or weird quirks when linking a DLL built with MFC100 to a DLL built with MFC90, or if it's a trivial concern.

**NOTES****

- I do **not** have the option of rebuilding DLL **ONE**.
- I have looked for free options to build applications on MFC90 using VS2010, but I have not successfully found a solution. I read that I could simply download the Windows SDK 6.01, but when I downloaded it from Microsoft there was no trace of MFC in it.
- I do **not** have the option to use VS2008 (except for VS2008 Express, which does not come with MFC).
- This is all company proprietary code, so I cannot post any of the source code.

**EDIT****

- I should probably mention that DLL **TWO** exports functions that take a pointer to the class exported by DLL **ONE** as their arguments.
- None of the exported classes are *derived* from MFC objects. The exported classes only use MFC objects as member variables, member function arguments, or internally inside member functions. I can't say this one 100% certainty, but I don't believe the classes make use of anything more than `CString`, or POD structures like `POINT` & `POSITION`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work out of the box. I have seen projects with mixed versions of MFC. The only problem is deployment. MFC 8.0 and 9.0 need a manifest (and are preferably deployed in WinSxs) whereas 7.x and 10.x can simply be placed in the same folder as your executables.

As long as you have the merge modules for MFC/CRT 9.0, no worries.

Comment: So far you seem to be correct. I've done several tests and not encountered any errors yet. However, so far the testing has been limited to one OS and we do run this software on multiple OSes (XP, Vista, Win7 32bit, and Win7 64bit).

Comment: My experience tells me that if the software runs on both XP and W7 x64, then there won't be any problems :)

Answer (score 1):

Without the source assuming the DLL's are proprietary themselves (the code + the MFC used with, or just one or the other) I would imagine that they'd be just as quirky as utilizing any kind of DLL that Microsoft provides themselves. So I'm sure it's trivial, in my experience which someone wrote a wrapper for WMPLib.DLL in it's own DLL, the file API for it didn't cause any underlying issues but the error handling was terrible, the portability from XP to vista and 7 wasn't an issue but passing the wrong value at the wrong time was. All in all, I think it just matters how well the internal functions are written to interface with the MFC.

Answer (score 1):

[To pass MFC-derived objects, or pointers to MFC objects and memory allocated by MFC, you must build an extension DLL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f22wcbea%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) I assume you are having an MFC extension DLL project. If you have a complex MFC object like CView embedded in a structure, then you probably are embedding a pointer to MFC object. MFC objects with a known, version-independent layout like CRect is OK to pass.

MFC extension dlls are not portable across multiple versions. From the documentation of [Extension DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/h5f7ck28%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) :

Both the client application and the extension DLL must use the same version of MFCx0.dll.

Thus you can't link an MFC 9 extension DLL with MFC 10 libs. You need to ask the author to rebuild with MFC10, or obtain VC9 to have the MFC 9 libs.

The reason being, if you have [memory layout mismatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) between the V9 class definition and the V10 one, you would have at best memory leak and at worst random crash if you try mix both, as offset of members in MFC objects can be different in different versions. When you write to an address thinking it is Foo::memberA could be overwriting Foo::memberB because the memory layout are different. Also static variables are stored in different places. Probably the first mismatch you would notice if you try mix MFC versions is [a debug assert in the runtime class checking](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/6998c4dd-ff9f-4097-803c-b84802b02c78) which is called pretty frequently in MFC.

Comment: None of the exported classes are *derived* from MFC objects. They only use MFC objects as member variables, inside the the member functions, or as arguments to member functions.

Comment: The root cause is memory layout mismatch, passing a class derived MFC is just one way to expose the bug. Passing an object with MFC variable embedded is another way.